# HTMl input type show first number and optional alphabetic keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image: if i change this is how iam getting]I am trying to show first numeric key board and on same to type alphabetic in optional on mobile phone after a long research got something as mentioned below but it doesn't work.

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9][A-Z]{3}" />
```

Comment: If you are asking "How do I get mobile browsers to show the numeric keypad first?" the answer is you can't - it's browser dependent..

Comment: @rybo111, am using this to create a application which will be later converted into a mobile application

Answer (score 0):

This will open numeric keypad.

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9][A-Z]{3}" />
```

Check on this [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/kowozu/edit?html,output) demo

In my mobile this is how it behaved...

**Platform : Android (Jelly Bean)

Browser : Chrome**

**Initially...**
[image]

**After clicking on the <kbd>abc</kbd> in the bottom-left corner...**
[image]

**Platform : Android (Lollipop)

Browser : Chrome**

**Initially...**
[image]

**After clicking on the <kbd>Abc</kbd> in the bottom-left corner...**
[image]

Comment: Tested on my friends `Lollipop` device, updated the answer with its screenshots. Working on that device too.

Comment: u can check my updated answer it is not working that just shows number key pad